# Office Web Apps Server 2013 - Cache issue

Tags: ms-office, ms-wopi

Please, consider this scenario:

- I open file A.pptx and take it in view mode
- Click on "Edit in browser" button and file opens in edit mode correctly.
- Then, open file B.pptx in view mode.
- Click on "Edit in browser" button and OWA opens file A.pptx contents in edit mode but using file B.pptx properties.

I think it's some related with cache but I cannot solve it.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE 20151222:**

I was able to reproduce this behavior using Excel Web App getting same results.

It seems like it's something related with "SessionID" based on some Event Viewer log entries:

[Event Viewer - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqFiz.png)

Here's the code fragment I'm using to generate these IDs:

[Code Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWvL7.png)

Thanks any help.

Comment: Have you resolved the problem already? Looking at the images attached, it seems the code is different from the marx-yu/WopiHost which you used as a reference, [if I'm not mistaken](https://github.com/marx-yu/WopiHost/commit/cffbab17b6a62b743b23d32d210e0eb5c799603c#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8). Could you perhaps put your code into your GitHub repo so that we can check out what's wrong?